# What is the preferred approach to initialize one-time logic in ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, application-state

*Scenario:*

- I have a ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms based website.
- It contains `Foo.aspx`, `Bar.aspx` and `baz.html` (jQuery template).
- Typical traffic seen is `Foo.aspx` (N times), `Bar.aspx` (N times) and `baz.html` (10*N times).
- ASP.NET worker process (`aspnet_wp.exe`) is recycled say every 2 hours.
- There exists an older API (`OldFooService.Init()`) which needs to be executed only for the first request of `Foo.aspx`. `OldFooService.Init()` initializes a data-store into `Cache` for the very first flow, but fires blanks for subsequent flows.

*Question:*

I am currently doing B (see below) since the traffic to `Foo.aspx` is lower than `baz.html` and `OldFooService.Init()` fires blanks after the first time.

Should I use C? Writing to `Application_State` requires locking ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf.aspx)) and its not guaranteed to be available, so not sure if its worth the effort. Or is there a much better D?

*Options:*

A) In `Application_Start` of `Global.asax`

B) In `Page_Load` of `Foo.aspx` once (by checking `Not IsPostBack`)

C) Option B + use a flag in `ApplicationState` to run once per recycle of `aspnet_wp.exe`.

Comment: The answer seems extremely obvious, A. I'm curious why you are hesitating and decided to ask on SO?

Comment: Updated my question. The older service needs to run only for the very first request of Foo.aspx. Since the traffic is higher to baz.html and also aspnet_wp.exe is recycled constantly, which doesn't require the older service, I am hesitant to initialize in Global.asax.

Comment: Application_Start only fires once, when the worker process starts, doing this once every 2 hours doesn't seem bad. What type of Cache are we talking about?

Comment: The older service uses HttpContext.Current.Cache.

Comment: How large of a cache are we talking about?  From start to finish, how long does it take your OldFooService.Init() to run?  What's the memory footprint?

Comment: You could wrap the cache in a class and lazy load it, but I still think Application_Start is the best option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer here is (A), use Global.asax.  B won't work as subsequent GET requests will run the same code. C will work, but is ugly as sin.

I would recommend handling Application_Start or Application_Init in Global.asax, depending on what's required in your legacy init function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I didn't word my scenario correctly. The older service needs to run only for the very first request of Foo.aspx. Since the traffic is higher to baz.html and also aspnet_wp.exe is recycled constantly, which doesn't require the older service, I am hesitant to initialize in Global.asax.

Comment: The question is, is N > 1 (number of times Foo.aspx is accessed) during the 2-hour lifecycle of your worker process?  If so, it still makes sense to locate the logic in Global.asax.  Also, why is your worker process recycled so often?

Answer (score 1):

If it's ok for  OldFooService.Init() to be called a few extra times in the event of requests coming in simultaneously before its initialized then I would go with C.  If it absolutely must run once per recycle, then I would use a static class with some proper read/write locks.

On a side note, is the worker process actually recycled every 2 hours?  That seems rather frequent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The frequent recycling is just a side-effect of automated builds to dev/test environments. I can see how my words paint the wrong context, will take note to avoid this in future.